# Bootstrap banner in tablet view

Tags: gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a web layout with bootstrap 3 where in a main container has divided into two part, `col-md-9` (left), and `col-md-3` (right), the right side contains two banner (as screen shot), the problem is when it view in iPad, the banner is not align within the main container, is there any workaround to resolve this matter in tablet devices such as iPad?

[image]

```
<div class="container" role="main">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-9">//carousel</div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <p><img class="img-response" style="" src="images/263x120-1.jpg"></p>
          <p><img class="img-response" style="" src="images/263x120-2.jpg"></p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class for images needs to be img-responsive not img-response